# How to instantiate a class given its name as a string?

Tags: python

Give some class definitiona in python, e.g.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

class B(object):
    def __init(self):
        self.x = 42
```

I want to instantiate one of these classes given its name as string. So for example, if `classname` is `A`, then I want to do something like

```
myinstance = SOMETHING(classname)
```

which should correspond to

```
myinstance = A()
```

Is there a way to do this without the use of eval `eval` or maps? If not, I would do the following:

```
map = {'A': A, 'B': B}
myinstance = map[classname]()
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: `myinstance = locals()[classname]()`

Comment: @dano: Its not about calling a class method by a name given in a string.

Comment: @Alex: no, it is about calling a class given a name in a string. But to Python, there is no difference between a class and a function.

Comment: @Alex Just do exactly what the top two answers in that question say, but pass your class' name instead of a function name.

Comment: @all: I see, then this is probably a duplicate. If Martin says so, it must be....

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the Python naming scheme is based on maps, you will be using maps of one sort or another even if you use `eval`.

Building your own map is the most appropriate, but you can also use `globals()` or retrieve it from a module if your classes are stored somewhere else:

```
import util_module
getattr(util_module, 'A') ()
```